# Another (perhaps humorous) term for "The Gold Standard"

Tags: word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests

Gold Standard as in:

> an example against which others of the same type are compared
>   - http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/gold%20standard

Any other humorous ways to refer to this?

Something like "the holy mother"...

Comment: Why do you think that 'Gold Standard' has something humorous about it?

Comment: @Josh61, I don't, I'm looking for a humour replacement for it.  Something that means the same thing, but is a little punchier and less like a salesperson describing their favorite product.

Comment: Could you add a context where you would like to use this?

Comment: Oh, I think there's some bad humor. The only reason the term is used to mean this is either a bad pun or a gross misunderstanding of its original meaning. The journals I work on tend to avoid it or put it in quotation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps **[the mother of all ...](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+mother+of+all)**

> an extreme example of something - *Mike's suffering from the mother of all hangovers after the party last night.*

If you want something with a continental flair, consider **[ne plus ultra](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ne+plus+ultra)**

> The highest point, as of excellence or achievement; the ultimate.

If it's a personal analogy you seek, you could follow my 91 year old Dad's lead, bragging when he finished a large bowl of shellfish,

> *I'm the **Derek Jeter** of mussels!*

Comment: In line with the last point, many people use the name of a current (or at least recent) sports star, e.g. the *Michael Jordan* or *Tiger Woods* of <x>. Popularity of such celebrities often wanes relatively rapidly with time (or scandal), so this is more common in speech than in writing.